# Twig filter chaining and priorities

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having diffculties trying to find the right syntax for a multiple Twig filter expression.

I have a var called **floatVar** which is not always defined.

If it is defined, I would like to truncate this float to the third digit.
If it is not defined, I would like to set an empty string.

I'm having trouble finding the proper syntax:

```
floatVar|number_format(3, '.','')|default('') // generates a Twig_Error_Runtime exception

floatVar|default('')|number_format(3, '.','') // output "0" in every case

(floatVar|number_format(3, '.',''))|default('') // generates a Twig_Error_Runtime exception
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction ? Is there a way to put paranthesis to explictly express the priority ?
Any help or link to a related topic would be much appreciated.

Have a good day.

Comment: Try with this

{{ yourelement != null ? yourelement|round(3, 'floor') : '' }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct order would be :

```
{{ floatVar|default(0)|number_format(3, '.','') }}
```

- **default(0)** : first you ensure that floatVar has a default value (even if it's not defined)
- **number_format(3, '.','')** : then you format it

however, this would print 0.000 if floatvar isn't defined.

if you want to do this in 1 line, you should consider creating a custom twig extension : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

EDIT :
Following @Pierre Olivier's answer, you should try :

```
{{ floatVar is defined ? floatVar|number_format(3, '.','') : '' }}
```

(`yourelement != null` will raise an error if yourelement isn't defined)

Comment: The EDIT you suggested made it work, thanks !
I was trying to avoid having 0.000 and the ternary solved it indeed.
It's just a shame parenthesis and priorities do not work for those cases...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

{{ yourelement != null ? yourelement|round(3, 'floor') : '' }}

Comment: For some strange reason, I can't make the round filter to work. However, the EDIT @Basile has suggested based on your ternary made it work ! So thanks !